# check all items under a parent node in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, tree

I am trying to check all the childnodes under a parent node, the code I have so far only goes about 2-3 levels deep in the TreeView and I am looking to grab all nodes no matter how deep they are. Could someone shed some insight on this.

Below is the code:

```
Private Sub CheckChildNode(ByVal currNode As TreeNode)
    'set the children check status to the same as the current node
    Dim checkStatus As Boolean = currNode.Checked
    For Each node As TreeNode In currNode.Nodes
        node.Checked = checkStatus
        CheckChildNode(node)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub CheckParentNode(ByVal currNode As TreeNode)
    Dim parentNode As TreeNode = currNode.Parent
    If parentNode Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    parentNode.Checked = True
    For Each node As TreeNode In parentNode.Nodes
        If Not node.Checked Then
            parentNode.Checked = False
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    CheckParentNode(parentNode)
End Sub

Private Sub treeview_AfterCheck(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As
System.Windows.Forms.TreeViewEventArgs) Handles treeview.AfterCheck
RemoveHandler treeview.AfterCheck, AddressOf treeview_AfterCheck
    CheckChildNode(e.Node)
    CheckParentNode(e.Node)
    AddHandler treeview.AfterCheck, AddressOf treeview_AfterCheck
End Sub
```

Comment: could format the code better ;-)

Comment: Duplicate from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370420/treeview-check-and-uncheck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get all subnodes no matter how deep they are, you definitely need recursion.

That is, you take each direct child of a node and do the check for this node. And you also call the method to check subnodes for each child.

So here in Pseudocode.

```
node getParentNode(node child){
 return child.parent
}

node checkNode(node n){
 // perform check here for node n
 if n is not valid {
  return false!
 }
 // do children recursively
 for each child in n.children{
  // function calls itself!
  checkNode(child)
 }
}
```

[Here](http://visualbasic.about.com/od/quicktips/qt/recursion.htm)'s a recursion tutorial for vb.net. [Here](http://erwnerve.tripod.com/prog/recursion/), [here](http://cse.unl.edu/~dsadofs/RecursionTutorial/index.php) and [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/print/lesson16.html) is you can find additional information.

Comment: Another way to have all nodes checked is to insert this code in your AfterCheck statment.

    Private Sub myTree_AfterCheck(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.TreeViewEventArgs) Handles tvFiles.AfterCheck
        Dim t As TreeNode
        For Each t In e.Node.Nodes
            t.Checked = e.Node.Checked
        Next
    End Sub